# React Text Annotation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highlight

I'm working on a React app where users can select text and add simple annotations. In addition, previous annotations will be loaded from an API via JSON.

The annotations JSON looks something like this:

```
"annotations": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "start": 12,
    "end": 67,
    "text": "Annotation Text"
  }
]
```

Where `start` and `end` are the character locations in the HTML, which is also loaded via JSON and `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. So when new annotations are added, their character locations need to match up when the annotations are saved back to the API.

Ideally, annotations are also highlighted in the UI.

Any suggestions on how to do this? AnnotatorJS doesn't seem to be maintained very well, so I'm nervous about using it in a production project.

Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you render out those characters inside a span (or some other element) and add whatever styling you like? I would recommend against using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` if possible and use jsx elements.

Answer (score 3):

Use react-text-annotate
A React component for interactively highlighting parts of text.
https://github.com/mcamac/react-text-annotate/

Here is the link for the [demo](https://mcamac.github.io/react-text-annotate) for text annotations in react

Comment: The following version is less buggy, actively developed with additional features:
gh: https://github.com/smhaley/react-text-annotate-blend

demo: https://smhaley.github.io/react-text-annotate-blend/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with DBS above in creating two divs, one that with annotated styling and one without. Figure out the text that you want annotated, via matching (.contains() or regex) or whatever your case is, and render those texts in a div with a class how you want styled.

First, I would probably push all the text into an array, maybe make them into objects with a boolean value, isAnnotated, and then map the array into JSX. If the text isAnnotated equals true, then use the annotated-text CSS class for that string of text, otherwise else push them into a classless div.

```
const Footer = (props) => {
return(
<span>
 <div className='annotated-text'>{annotatedText}</div>
 <div> className='other-text'>{otherText}</div>
</span>
)}
```